# Compilation error on linux server (C project)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, include

I need some help.

I worked on a C project locally and it ran perfect with no issues at all.
Then I moved my whole project files to a linux server (using Bitwise) and ran it using the following command:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG main.c map.c map.h utilities.c 
utilities.h election.c election.h extended_map.c extended_map.h test_utilities.h -o outmap
```

and again everything worked as expected.

Now, I want to replace my version of `test_utilities.h` with the version saved on that server, so I opened `main.c` (which is the only file to include `test_utilities.h` and replaced:

```
#include "test_utilities.h"
```

with

```
#include "~mtm/public/1920b/ex1/test_utilities.h"
```

But the terminal shows me the following error:

```
gcc: error: test_utilities.h: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2$
```

As suggested I changed it to

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG main.c map.c map.h utilities.c utilities.h election.c election.h extended_map.c extended_map.h test_utilities.h -o outmap -I ~mtm/public/1920b/ex1/
```

But still I get the following:

gcc: error: test_utilities.h: No such file or directory

**update2: (I was requested to remove .h files so now I got)**

```
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG main.c map.c utilities.c election.c extended_map.c -o outmap
```

Comment: Does it work if you manually specify the full path to your home directory instead of `~mtm`?

Comment: But that's the root, what do u mean?

Comment: It is unacceptable here to deface your post once it's been answered according to the site's Terms of Service. Please do not do so again. If you continue to deface your posts as you've done twice now, I'm going to flag them for a moderator's attention and you may end up suspended, which would mean you are unable to ask questions here in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Writing `~mtm` to refer to the home directory of user `mtm` is a shortcut that your shell understands. It isn't something that the C preprocessor understands. So you'll have to spell it out as `/home/mtm` (or wherever `mtm`'s home directory is located) instead of `~mtm`.

That said, a better way would be to just leave it as `"test_utilities.h"` and instead adjust the include path of the compiler (specified via `-I` when invoking the compiler) to include `~mtm/public/1920b/ex1/`.

You also shouldn't specfiy `test_utilities.h` as an argument to the compiler. In fact none of the header files should be passed as arguments to the compiler.

Comment: @smith_97 Leave the include as `#include "test_utilities.h"` and add the option `-I ~mtm/public/1920b/ex1/` when you call `gcc`. With that option you can include any files from the directory by just specifying their names.

Comment: But not all of my files are under that directory... some of them under the current one kindly read my last update in the main quesiton

Comment: @smith_97 `-I` adds include directories, it doesn't override existing ones. That is, adding a directory via `-I` won't make includes from other directories (including the current directory) stop working.

Comment: @smith_97 About you still getting that error: The error you're getting is actually about you specifying `test_utilities.h` on the command line. It doesn't currently even get to the error at the `#include`. As mentioned in my last paragraph, you shouldn't be listing header files on the command line at all.

Comment: Could you add full example, what do u mean not to list header files? I need to compile them

Comment: @smith_97 When you call `gcc`, don't add the names of the header files. Currently you command line looks like `gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG main.c map.c map.h ...` and I'm saying `map.h` shouldn't be on there, nor should any of the other header files - particularly not test_utilities.h.

Comment: I was required to write makefile and there I included the header files...

Comment: @smith_97 You're not ignoring them if you're including them in your .c files. Invoking the compiler on a header file does nothing. And invoking the compiler on a header file that doesn't exist causes it to abort with an error.

Comment: @smith_97 In a makefile header files should be listed as the dependencies of the .c files that include them (if you don't manage that automatically), but not as an argument to the compiler.

Comment: @smith_97 You seem to have also removed the `-I` in your latest command line. So now you should actually be getting an error about the include, rather than the command line argument. And if you add the `-I`, that error should go away (assuming it currently says `#include "test_utilities.h"` in your .c file).

Comment: *** No rule to make target `test_utilities.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.

Comment: @smith_97 If you list `test_utilities.h` as a dependency, you'll need to specify its full path. But as I understood it, you're including it from a directory that doesn't belong to you, right? Then you won't be modifying, so it doesn't need to be listed as a dependency. It's more like including a system/library header. So just remove it from the makefile.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688037/makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target-how-to-solve-it please take a look, I need to upload the files within 2 hours