# makefile error "No rule to make target" how to solve it?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

what's wrong with my makefile?

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c map.h election.h test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
map.o: map.c map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o: election.c election.h map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

I am running the following command on linux:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls
election.c  extended_map.c  main.c  makefile  mtm_map           utilities.c
election.h  extended_map.h  main.o  map.h     test_utilities.h  utilities.h
-bash-4.2$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `map.c', needed by `map.o'.  Stop.
-bash-4.2$
```

map.c exists inside a folder named `mtm_map` inside the current folder

Comment: The makefile expects `map.c` to be in the current folder, not a subdirectory.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to deface your question after it's been posted according to the Terms of Service. Please do not do so again.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: mod message: post locked. Please don't rollback anymore after the lock period.

Answer (score 1):

You told make how to build "map.o" out of "map.c", but you don't have "map.c". You have "mtm_map/map.c".

You probably want something like

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c map.h election.h test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
mtm_map/map.o: mtm_map/map.c map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o: election.c election.h map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _changing $*.c_ but there's no way to fix your problem by changing the content of the recipe.  Make doesn't care about the content of the recipe; it simply hands it off to the shell.  In order to fix your problem you'll have to change the target and prerequisites, as shown here.

Comment: @Chad Miller provided you with a solution to the question you asked, and that solution worked for that question.  Now you've asked a different question, that is not related to the first one.  SO is not intended to be a "running tutorial session". It's intended that you first try to solve your problem, then if you can't you post a question for that specific problem describing what you have tried and what didn't work.  In your comment above for example you say "a new error" but you don't tell us what source file failed to compile.

Comment: Most likely you need to add `-I$(CURDIR)` to your compile line (the `COMP_FLAG` variable) so that the compiler can find your header files.

Comment: His code _DID_ work, in that the problem you had before _No rule to make target_ is now gone.  Problem solved.  Now you have a _new_ and different problem, which is your compile fails because it can't find a header file.  There's no way we can foresee this new problem because it depends on the content of all your source files and what they include, and how.  You need to use the `-I` compiler flag once for each directory that contains your header files that you want to include.  If they're all in one directory, you just need it once with that directory.

Comment: The compiler is not going to go searching through your entire system (or even the subdirectories of the current directory) trying to find files.  You have to tell it where they are.

Comment: Since the original problem was that `map.o` gave an error "No rule to build", I don't see how running `make main.o` would result in "the same old error"... that's a completely different file.

Comment: Above you said that the error was for `utilities.h`.  Why would changing the include for `map.h` help with a problem including `utilities.h`?  They're totally different files.  Anyway, this is why you should ask a new question, then you can add the details for that question in a full question text box with the necessary information rather than trying to cram it into a comment text box.

Comment: That IS an error in Chad's makefile.  You need to add the `-o $@` option to all your rules (in particular the one that generates `mtm_map/map.o` but it's best to do it for all of them.

Comment: Why would we mention changing includes to `map.h` when the error reported by you was for `utilities.h`?  And why should we spontaneously suggest you change that include when we have no idea what is in your source files?  We had no way of knowing you didn't already have `mtm_map/map.h` in all your includes.  Anyway.  Glad you got it working.  Cheers!